# Equation involving; elastic modulus, poisson ratio, radius and pressure of a sphere

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

I am trying to determine the expansion of a spherical pressure vessel. I am certain that an equation exist that will define the change of radius of the sphere as the pressure increases. The vessel will change from atmospheric pressure to an internal pressure of 8 bar. Is there an equation to calculate to radial change?

Comment: Did you try [the obvious Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pressure%20expansion%20of%20sphere)? At the time of writing the top link from the search contains a formula that answers your question.

Comment: @JohnRennie I have, although there were several conflicting equations that produced different results.

Comment: This is not a homework question, I am developing a gripper as an engineering application. I simply had difficulty finding/understanding the equation. Narasimham has answered this question accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vessel thickness $t$ is made of a material of elastic modulus $E$, Poisson's ratio $ \nu $ the bi-axial strain as well as radial strain is

$$   \epsilon = \Delta R / R = \dfrac{p\cdot R ( 1-\nu)}  { 2\; t E}$$

and radial dilatation:

$$ \Delta R = \dfrac{p\cdot R^2 ( 1-\nu)}  { 2\; t E}$$

EDIT1

This is how the equation is derived:

Considering a hemisphere acted upon by pressure $p$ force balance is:

$$ 2 \pi R t  \sigma = p \pi R^2  $$

Membrane stress $$\sigma _x = \sigma _y =  \sigma  =  \dfrac{p\cdot R}{2 t}$$

in all directions due to isotropic character of vessel wall.
Membrane strain $ \epsilon _x =  \epsilon_y  =  \dfrac{p\cdot R}{2 t E}$

Resulting strain taking into consideration  Poisson effect $ = ( \epsilon_x -\nu\; \epsilon_y ) =  \dfrac{p\cdot R}{2 t E}(1-\nu) $

Comment: Your answers can't be right just on dimensional grounds: your second equation has dimensions of length (I'm guessing that you mean $t$ to be the thickness of the pressure vessel)

Comment: I would suggest that you change your $\mu$ to $\nu$, as is standard notation for Poisson's ratio. $\mu$ is more commonly (read: always) the shear modulus, which may be a source of confusion.

Comment: as you indicated..